# how to connect mysql with jdbc connector/J 8.0.11 latest 2018?

Tags: mysql, sql, eclipse, connector-j

connector/J 8.0.11 has some changes due to which older line of code is not working for connection.

Answer (score 0):

the right way to latest connection is:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBname?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "username", "password");

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
```